# Android: Why doesn't my Service start?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, service

I want to learn how to use services in my application, but Service doesn't work! Here is my code.
This is the sample code i have written  for the services. Suggest me if i am missing anything.Thanks in Advance

```
package com.example.utente.test;

import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
final String[] numeri =
{"1","2","1","2","1","2","1","2","1","2","1","2","1","2","1","2","1","2","1","2"
,"1","2","1","2",
"1","2","1","2","1","2","1","2","1","2","1","2","1","2","1","2","1","2","1","2",
"1","2","1","2"};
long inizio;
long fine;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
inizio = System.currentTimeMillis();
Intent i= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
startService(i);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
R.layout.riga, numeri);
ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onResume()
{
super.onResume();
inizio = System.currentTimeMillis();
//     new MyService(inizio);
}
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adattatore, final View componente,
int posizione, long id )
{
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), numeri[posizione],
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
package com.example.utente.test;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MyService extends Service
{
long inizio;
long fine;
long tempo;
boolean ciclo=true;
int prova=0;
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
// This is where you would place your code that you want in the
background
// Putting your while loop here will make sure it runs when the app is closed
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() ,"COMMAND",
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
while(ciclo)
{
fine = System.currentTimeMillis();
tempo = (fine-inizio)/1000;
if(tempo>10 && prova==0)
{
prova++;
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "10s",
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
return Service.START_STICKY;
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
//TODO for communication return IBinder implementation
return null;
}
}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.utente.test">
<service
android:name="MyService" />
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I am not even going to read a code so badly formatted.

Comment: If you format your code like that, you'll get a lot of headaches when you'll try to read it in the future.

Comment: now can you help me?

Comment: Not without reading the code. And nobody is going to read it, if it's formatted like that.

Comment: remove the redundant spaces please/

Comment: Now, after the last edit, the code needs proper indentation. Any volunteer?

Answer (score 0):

Add your `Service` to your `Manifest` as followed:

```
<service android:name=".MyService" />
```